# In Doctrine, do I need do create a class only to make a join?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to make a join in my repository class (Symfony 3 with Doctrine).

This is how it looks like:

```
public function findByRole($roles){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->join('user_role', 'ur', Join::ON, 'ur.id = u.customerId');
        $q = $qb->getQuery();

        $users = $q->getArrayResult();
        dump($users);
    }
```

And I've got this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 49 near 'user_role ur': Error: Class
>   'user_role' is not defined.

There are two entity classes defined - User and Role. And Role is a property of User (ManyToMany).

There is also a joining table - user_role - do I need to create a class for every joining table even if I don't need it for my own purposes?

p.s.
I know this error can be already found on Stackoverflow, but people having this issue probably have different problems.

**Update:**

Here's the User entity class (shortened):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    //irrelevant code removed

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role", cascade = {"persist"}, inversedBy="users")
    *  @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
    *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id",
    * referencedColumnName="id")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id",
    * referencedColumnName="id")}
    *      )
     */
    private $roles;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public function __construct() {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////
    //roles

    /**
     * Add role
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Role $role
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(\AppBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setRoles(\AppBundle\Entity\Role $role){
        $this->addRole($role);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Remove role
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Role $role
     */
    public function removeRole(\AppBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
        $this->roles->removeElement($role);
    }

    /**
     * I know it probably should return simply $this->roles, but the interface I'm implementing requires an array of strings... But everything works fine, except joining user+roles  
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRoles() {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRoleEntities() {
        return $this->roles;
    }



}
```

Comment: It should be `u.user_role`.

Comment: @qooplmao thanks, but now I have this: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 61 near 'ur ON ur.id =': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\User has no association named user_role what actually this 'u' means? I thought that it means user table, and there is no 'user_role' field, the 'user_role' is a completely different table (which joins users and roles)

Comment: I assumed `user_role` was the property with relationship between `user` and `roles`. If there is no relationship then you will need one. Also **probably have different problems** kind of gives off the impression that you couldn't be bothered to look through the other answers.

Comment: No, it only means I did try to understand what their **questions**, and then looked at the anwers, but I know too little about Symfony, I've just noticed that I **probably** have problems with my mapping (annotations), and the answers did not mention it.

Comment: Fair enough, just saying that's how it looks. From your update it looks like you would just need to use `->join('u.roles', 'ur');`

Comment: Thanks, although I did it a bit differently - after I corrected my mappings, it appears that I don't have to explicitly join tables, because Doctrine does it for me:) But thank you for your time, so +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doctrine, all joined objects must be entities.

But you can map a many-to-many relationship between the entities User and Role, using user_role as a linkage table

In user table you might have a property `$roles`

```
/**
* @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
* @JoinTable(name="user_role",
*      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id",
* referencedColumnName="id")},
*      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id",
* referencedColumnName="id")}
*      )
*/
private $roles;
```

and a property `$users` in role table

```
    /**
* @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="roles")
* @JoinTable(name="user_role",
*      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id",
* referencedColumnName="id")},
*      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id",
* referencedColumnName="id")}
*      )
*/
private $users;
```

I've not tested this code. Surely It gonna need some tweeking.
You also need to created the getters and setters for these properties.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed have no "users" property in Role, but according to this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional this is OK, they call it many-to-many unidirectional... But OK, I'll try your changes

Comment: Yes. No problem. You're allowed to do it unidirectionally :)

Comment: Now I have "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 61 near 'ur ON ur.id =': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\User has no association named user_role" - I also changed (just for testing) inversedBy to mappedBy = "users" above Role:$users, but this did not help. And using php bin/console doctrine:schema:valid
 shows:

Comment: [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\Role' mapping is invalid:
* The association AppBundle\Entity\Role#users refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\User#users which does not exist.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\User' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings AppBundle\Entity\User#roles and AppBundle\Entity\Role#users are inconsistent with each other.

[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
What does it mean?

Comment: Could you show me the code you are using in the user side?

Comment: You mean User entity? If so, then I've just updated my question.

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is because getRoles() method. It must return a Collection, unfortunatelly this method is invoked by QueryBuilder... Hold on I'm editing you code for suggesting something.

Comment: So what can I do? The entire login/security system requires that this function exists and returns a simple array...

Comment: Take a look a at you getRoles(). Have you changed findByRole() ? It's required that you change it to reflect the new mapping...

Comment: Omar, do you know an article which will explain me what is "inversedBy", "mappedBy" etc? Maybe this will be simpler, I think that without a good understanding I will have problems all the time, and somehow I don't quite understand Symfony's docs :(

Comment: Well.... the best reference I know is the doctrine documetation. But I know something you might try out. Try to rename the $roles property in User to something like $userRoles. And in your query builder you can refer it as 'user.userRoles' (dont forget the accessors) and do the join. Create an alternative melhod getRoles() to fulfill your authentication system :)

Comment: Hi Omar. I finally (almost) managed to solve this problem, after implementing your changes, re-reading Doctrine docs and changing the "findByRole" function. First of all I understood that I should use classes names (like AppBundle\Entity\Role) rather than table names (?), plus: Doctrine joins tables on its own, so simple  "$this->createQueryBuilder('u')" seems to do the job. Except that now I don't know how to add a "where" statement to filter users by role, but that's another story:) So thank you again!

Comment: as I wrote above, it works, but now I don't know how to add a where on the role.role_name column, could you please look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175779/implicit-joins-and-where-in-doctrine-how ?