# Implicit joins and Where in Doctrine - how?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have a ManyToMany relation of Users and Roles. That is I have User table and entity class, Role table and entity and a joining table "user_role" width user_id and role_id columns.

Now, I recently tried to get users with their roles, by using joins, like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->join('user_role', 'ur', Join::ON, "I didn't know what to put here, nothing worked ")
```

Anyway, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154354/in-doctrine-do-i-need-do-create-a-class-only-to-make-a-join) answer I added correct mapping (annotations) to my both entity classes and then removed my own join, letting Doctrine do the job:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$q = $qb->getQuery();
$users = $q->getResult();
```

And this works. I have a list of all users, and then I can access their roles (thanks to User->getRoles() method).

However, now I want to list only users having certain roles, for example 'ROLE_ADMIN' and I have no idea how to do this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
>where('what_to_put_here = :roles')
->setParameter('roles', 'what_to_put_here')
```

By the way, the SQL code generated by Doctrine looks like this:

```
SELECT u0_.id AS id_0, u0_.username AS username_1, u0_.personal_name AS personal_name_2, u0_.password AS password_3, u0_.email AS email_4, u0_.is_active AS is_active_5 FROM user u0_
```

So there is no JOIN. From the Doctrine docs I know this is called "lazy load" - the roles of certain user will be fetched on demand.

But then, how can I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` 
JOIN user_role on user_role.user_id = user.id
JOIN role on role.id = user_role.role_id
WHERE role.role_name = 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->innerJoin('u.roles', 'r')
    ->where('r.roleName = :roleNameParameter')
    ->setParameter('roleNameParameter', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

I'm assuming you mapped the column role_name as property roleName in the entity.

Comment: Thanks, but this results in [Semantical Error] line 0, col 67 near 'role_name = ': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Role has no field or association named role_name :( Is this because in the class it is called roleName? (camel case instead of underscore). But in database I use underscores, because I believe this is a standard when developing in Symfony, right? So what can I do about it? I mean this time I can simply rename it to "name" instead of "role_name" but I don't think this is the best way.... I mean next time it may happen that this will have to be more than one word.

Comment: I added getrole_name method to class Role and nothing changed.

Comment: ? Can you help please?

Comment: Hi @konrad_firm, pay close attention to the names that you use inside WHERE clause. You must use the names mapped at your entity, not the column name.

For example, if mapped the column role_name as roleName, the where show be r.roleName. I found another mistake in this answer and I'm editing it now.

Comment: @omar-alves It works! Thank you both! (I also found this mistake, you mean wrong parameter name?)

Comment: there was two mistakes: the column name instead of property name. And the parameter name was not matching the place holder. I just changed the parameter name to distinguish better of the column/property name. :)

Comment: @omar-alves Thank you Omar :)